# Stripe isn't retrieving invoices with test clocks

Tags: stripe-payments

I use Stripe API to retrieve all invoices like this:

`stripe invoices list --limit=10000`

and I got 64 items(the `data` array has the length of 64).

I checked the invoices listed in my Stripe dashboard and there're 310 results in total and I realized that invoices with test clock is not returned by API. How can I get all invoices with test clocks like the way in the Stripe dashboard?

Comment: That sounds unlikely and you could write to Stripe Support providing your request id on https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/logs and your Invoice Ids with test clocks which you expect to show up, and they could help dive deeper into.